# DeployOnBuild not working with VS2017 MSBuild tools

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy, visual-studio-2017

i installed the VS2017 build tools with `vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --quiet`
but now when I build with the installed MSbuild, passing the /p:DeployOnBuild=true, there seems to be no attempt to do any of the config transformation, aspnet compilation, or deployment that happens when i use the v14.0 tools.

what extra magic incantation do i have to do to make this work?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Maybe this issue will solve it. https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901

Comment: My targests were missing

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you use the proper MSBuild.exe.
This:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

Or if IDE (enterprise) installed:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

If configure an MSBUILD step in a TFS server, set the path of the MSBUILD.exe manualy (Advenced/MSBuild/Specify location):
[image: Set TFS MSBuild step]

Using this: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

will cause that no deployment package created.

Comment: Thank you!  I found 31 versions of "msbuild.exe" on my server, but this is the right one

Comment: This helped me. Once using the right msbuild, I also removed the "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0" parameter I used to use, and it started publishing again (just publishing from command line with VS 2017 installed, not using any other tool)